# Why do integers and pointers get a different type of random values when declared in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

As I understood pointers are actually integers that can store the address of another variable as their value. Like any non-static variable when declared and not initialized they get related to a random value.
But why do the random values are in different numeral systems.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main(){
int a; 

int *p; 

cout << a << "     " <<p << endl; 
    return 0; 

}
```

Console:

```
198271008     0x10bd1cc20
```

Comment: Because C++ does not initialize variables for you. You have to do that explicitly yourself. So use `int a = 0;` (or `int a{0}`) and `int *p{nullptr};` The reason for this is that C++ has a basic rule "Do not pay for what you do not use", so if initialization is not always necessary C++ will not pay for it.

Comment: Unless you explicitly initialize local variables, they will have an *indeterminate* value (not random even though it might seem like that). And in C++ using indeterminate values in any way, even just printing them, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "When I do something wrong, why does the system behave the way it does?" -- Is this what you're asking?  If you are, honestly this is not a productive way to learn C++, especially if you're a beginner.  You do something wrong, accept it's wrong and code correctly.  You will wind up wasting time trying to figure out "undefined behavior".

Comment: And while on most current systems a pointer basically is an integer value, it's still a type separate from other integer types. Pointers or any kind is printed in one way, because there's a specific [`operator<<` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for printing pointers. And that overload is different from the overload for `int`. The exact format for printing pointers isn't specified though, that's left for the implementation (standard library) to decide.

Comment: Do you mean why is the pointer printed in hex? that's just how streams generally work (though it's not specified by the standard)

Comment: *But why do the random values are in different numeral systems.* -- This has nothing to do with uninitialized variables.  Even if you initialized those variables, you will see similar output due to the way `cout` and `operator <<` works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not saying that I did something wrong or the system etc. I'm just wondering how it came like it came, so stop judging. Btw no one asked for a better way to learn sth....

Comment: @PepijnKramer oh okay. and why is the int given a normal real number and the pointer a hex number ? How did this happen in the background ?

Comment: Change the code to `int a{};` and  `int *p{};`.  PEBKAC problem solved.

Comment: @Ramyz -- It was already mentioned to you that `operator <<` handles integers and pointer values differently, so again, it has absolutely nothing to do with initialized or uninitialized variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks :)! What should I use instead ?

Comment: @Ramyz -- You have to tell `std::cout::operator <<` that you want to print the pointer in a certain way instead of the default (hex) way.  That's the general idea for any type you want to print in a certain way using `cout`.  To explain this in depth is way too broad, and should be found in any good C++ book and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: Whether a number is printed as decimal or hexadecimal doesn't matter - in both cases it's just a number. 30 and 0x1E is exactly the same thing, just displayed two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are generally presented in hexadecimal because that lines up with machine allocation requirements. Modern machines pretty much all have address sizes that are multiples of two, and hex simply condenses 4 bits into one hex digit. When machines had address sizes that were multiples of 3 they very often presented pointers in octal instead )condensing 3 bits into one octal digit).

Regular integers are printed in decimal because they are simply numbers and most of the time decimal is how a human expects to deal with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> But why do the random values are in different numeral systems.

Because `ostream::operator<<` is *overloaded* to accept different fundamental types and print them out in different ways.  The overloads that accept numeric types (in this case, `ostream::operator<<(int)`) print out the values in decimal form by default, whereas the overload that accepts any non-character pointer (in this case, `ostream::operator<<(const void*)`) prints out in hex form by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code and assumptions.

1. pointers are actually integers
2. when declared and not initialized they get related to a random value.
3. in different numeral systems

none of those are true.

1 - no, pointers have their own type - it is of type "pointer to variable of type ". A pointer to an integer is a different type than a pointer to a string. pointers can be caster to integral type like `int` or `long int` in which case you need to make sure that the integral type can even hold the value as `int` might be 32 bit while `float *` might be 64 bit.

2 - when you declare a variable and you do not initialise it explicitly the C++ language says the value is indeterminate, not random. What this means is that the language gives no guarantee on which value it will have (there are exceptions where variables will be initialised even if you do not explicitly give it a value not call its constructor). And further more reading the content of a not-initialised variable is undefined behaviour (the compiler is basically allowed to do whatever it wants).
What will happen on a lot of hardware/OS (but can not be relied upon) is that the variable will just hold the same bit-pattern as was previously stored in that location. But again this is undefined and in general can not be relied upon (nor should you EVER do that)

3 - there is no inherent number-system. What you are seeing is the default representation of that data-type by the standard library function `cout`. Fundamentally all data in a computer is just bits, but you as a developer tell the compiler how to format it in a human readable way. `cout` has some reasonable helpful default behaviour. For example for strings it will not print it as a long binary number, nor will it print its integral representation. Instead for integral types it will format them in base 10, for pointer-types it will be in hexadecimal. But those are just formatting of the value the hold. You can tell it to display them in whatever compatible way you like.